# Metadata lock on MySQL 5.7, can't find locking process?

Tags: mysql

So I have a python server with a (currently asleep) connection to the MySQL database. I go to phpMyAdmin and just try to truncate the "tools" table, which is part of the "organize" database. But it doesn't work. Problem is, I can't seem to find which query is actually locking it.

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db       | Command | Time | State                           | Info                   |
+-----+------+-----------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| 175 | user | localhost | organize | Sleep   | 1235 |                                 | NULL                   |
| 244 | user | localhost | NULL     | Query   |    0 | starting                        | show full processlist  |
| 307 | user | localhost | organize | Query   |  272 | Waiting for table metadata lock | TRUNCATE TABLE `tools` |
| 308 | user | localhost | NULL     | Sleep   |  272 |                                 | NULL                   |
+-----+------+-----------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

While the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` gives the following:

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| InnoDB |      |
=====================================
2017-03-16 14:18:08 0x7fa0da508700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 6 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 46 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 4115 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 4161
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 2
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 4, OS waits 2
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 4.00 RW-shared, 0.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 5384
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421804127426384, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
229 OS file reads, 390 OS file writes, 13 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 2232766
Log flushed up to   2232766
Pages flushed up to 2232766
Last checkpoint at  2232757
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
10 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 274857984
Dictionary memory allocated 317906
Buffer pool size   16384
Free buffers       16129
Database pages     255
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 203, created 52, written 370
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 255, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=25594, Main thread ID=140328678156032, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2782, updated 0, deleted 0, read 2792
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

And looking at `performance_schema.meta_locks` gives this:

```
mysql> select * from metadata_locks;
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA      | OBJECT_NAME      | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE           | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_STATUS | SOURCE            | OWNER_THREAD_ID | OWNER_EVENT_ID |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| TABLE       | organize           | AccessMatrixView |              72627408 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             334 |              4 |
| TABLE       | organize           | access_matrix    |              80700416 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             334 |              4 |
| TABLE       | organize           | people           |              81091984 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             334 |              4 |
| TABLE       | organize           | tools            |              79476128 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             334 |              7 |
| GLOBAL      | NULL               | NULL             |       140327657064288 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5496  |             335 |            170 |
| SCHEMA      | organize           | NULL             |       140327657360976 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5481  |             335 |            170 |
| TABLE       | organize           | tools            |       140327657150944 | EXCLUSIVE           | TRANSACTION   | PENDING     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             335 |            170 |
| TABLE       | performance_schema | metadata_locks   |       140327923115360 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             351 |             94 |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Can anyone help me diagnose the issue here?

Comment: Can you try running a `flush tables` statement and then run again the `truncate table`?

Comment: Tried that, there's no difference, but I did add the output of `performance_schema.meta_locks` above. (outputs are also the same whether or not I `flush` the tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to expand upon the other answer, this is the day I figure out `TRUNCATE` isn't equivalent to `DELETE FROM table`. Silly me.

Per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html):

> Logically, TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to a DELETE statement that deletes all rows, or a sequence of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements. To achieve high performance, it bypasses the DML method of deleting data. Thus, it cannot be rolled back, it does not cause ON DELETE triggers to fire, and it cannot be performed for InnoDB tables with parent-child foreign key relationships.
>
> Although TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to DELETE, it is classified as a DDL statement rather than a DML statement.`

Essentially, a process in the `SLEEP` state was reading the table, but the `TRUNCATE` was trying to do a DDL statement, hence it being blocked until the other `SLEEP`-ing process was killed.

Comment: I think this does not answer the title. I am having the same issue with many sleep process, which I can't kill directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's thread 335.

```
mysql> select * from metadata_locks;
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA      | OBJECT_NAME      | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE           | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_STATUS | SOURCE            | OWNER_THREAD_ID | OWNER_EVENT_ID |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| GLOBAL      | NULL               | NULL             |       140327657064288 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5496  |             335 |            170 |
| SCHEMA      | organize           | NULL             |       140327657360976 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5481  |             335 |            170 |
| TABLE       | organize           | tools            |       140327657150944 | EXCLUSIVE           | TRANSACTION   | PENDING     | sql_parse.cc:6030 |             335 |            170 |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
>>>>>> here >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> ^^^
```

The lock on organize.tools itself appears to actually be waiting for the other two locks held by the same thread.  Anything else needing a conflicting lock would wait behind these.

You can't see this thread in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` because the user you're logged in as does not have the `PROCESS` privilege, which allows you to see threads owned by other users and what they are doing.

> The `PROCESS` privilege pertains to display of information about the threads executing within the server (that is, information about the statements being executed by sessions). The privilege enables use of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `mysqladmin processlist` to see threads belonging to other accounts; you can always see your own threads
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process

Note that `mysqladmin processlist` (mentioned in the quote) is not a query you run -- it's a shell command that allows you to see the same information provided in response to the query `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I was executing: ALTER TABLE `Version` MODIFY COLUMN `version` VARCHAR(15);

Version is a table with only 1 row, without foreign keys, is a very simple table to store my current version of the code.

I spent multiple hours modifying the previous command but the problem was with the last SQL instruccion

I was asking in python with mysql:

> cur = execute("SELECT * FROM Version")

Then if my version is old

> execute(ALTER TABLE `Version` MODIFY COLUMN `version` VARCHAR(15);)
>   commit

Seems like the SELECT was locking the table, it was waiting for me to release, so I had to add the commit after the execute. This is the first time that I add a commit after a consult, I was committing only for instructions that modify the DB.

So the solution for me was to commit the last SQL instruction before the instruction that was getting locked.